# Schedule job between days

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2012, sql-agent-job

How to schedule a SSIS package between the 10th and 17th day of every month using a SQL Server agent job?

Between 10th and 17th the job should run every 30 minutes.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN DATEPART(DD, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 10 AND 17 
          THEN 1 
          ELSE 0
    END DAYSFLAG
```

I am not getting any idea, how to setup the job only to run between 10 and 17th of every month and every 30 minutes?

Please tell me how to achieve this task in a SQL Server agent job.

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule your job to run everyday every 30 minutes and then, at the beginning of your job, you can add a **Transact-SQL script (T-SQL)** step that checks if current day is between 10 and 17.

- if current day is between 10 and 17 the job will continue
- if current day is not between 10 and 17 the job will terminate. To terminate the script you can raise an error when the condition on calendar day is not met

To perform this check you can use something like this:

```
if DATEPART(DD, GETDATE()) not BETWEEN 10 AND 17 
    RAISERROR ('Current day is not between 10 and 17, the job must not run', 16, 1)
```

Comment: hi,if current day is not between 10 and 17 the job will terminate.  without give error.above script is giving error .how will design without failure job(even job is not between 10 and 17,

Answer (score 0):

in order to accomplish what you want, do what andrea suggested and create step 1 as Transact SQL which rasies error if day is not between 10 and 17. then go to the advanced tab and under "On failure action" select "Quit the job reporting success" that will terminate the job as success just for that step.